# Is the order in which ArcMap loads Extensions, Toolbars and Commands defined?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

When you extend Esri's ArcMap with both an Extension, a Toolbar and a number of Commands, is the order in which these categories are loaded by ArcMap well-defined? (I.e. are Commands always loaded before Toolbars, Extension always loaded before Commands, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcGIS Desktop 9.x, I'm pretty sure it is Extensions, Commands then Toolbars. I'd have to check with 10.0 since they are using a different method for loading custom code (although it's prob still the same)'

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading the "About extensions" topic in [Extending ArcObjects | ESRI Developer Network](https://web.archive.org/web/20080430031930/http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM/ExtendAO/AboutExtensions.htm) (*Wayback Machine link*)  which covers just-in-time extension loading.  Ideally all extensions should be JIT extensions.  Tools and commands can control the startup of a JIT extension etc.